# Difference of `route` and `ip route`

Tags: linux, networking, bash, routing

I'm using arch-linux.

`route` and `ip route` give basically the same information to me.

But `route` takes much more time than `ip route`.

What is the reason?

Comment: different code? what exactly are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: Why `route` takes more time than `ip route`?

Comment: That is like comparing apples to oranges. They are entirely different commands. If you're interested in what they're doing you can examine the source code or watch a truss or strace. ip route is meant to replace route, see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/523388/what-is-the-difference-between-route-and-ip-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in age:  `ip`, part of the `iproute2` package, is newer and intended to replace older tools such as `route`.

[The Linux Foundation explains](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2):

> Most network configuration manuals still refer to ifconfig and route
>   as the primary network configuration tools, but ifconfig is known to
>   behave inadequately in modern network environments. They should be
>   deprecated, but most distros still include them. Most network
>   configuration systems make use of ifconfig and thus provide a limited
>   feature set. The /etc/net project aims to support most modern network
>   technologies, as it doesn't use ifconfig and allows a system
>   administrator to make use of all iproute2 features, including traffic
>   control.
>
> iproute2 is usually shipped in a package called iproute or iproute2
>   and consists of several tools, of which the most important are ip and
>   tc. ip controls IPv4 and IPv6 configuration and tc stands for traffic
>   control. Both tools print detailed usage messages and are accompanied
>   by a set of manpages.

As documented by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2), `ip route` is intended as the replacement for `route` while `ip addr` and `ip link` will replace `ifconfig`.

Comment: Thanks. I found than `route -n` is almost as fast as `ip route`. So it could be DNS or something (maybe?). Anyway, thankQ!

Comment: @thelastblack Yes, `route -n` avoids DNS lookups.